# Extjs5: How to query a component by various properties

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Given a component like this:

```
{xtype: 'textfield', name: 'title', fieldLabel: 'Title', autoFocus: true}
```

Is it possible to query for all items in an arbitary container (say a window) that have an attribute `autoFocus` to call the method `.focus(...)` on it?

Tried...

`'[autoFocus]'`

`'*[autoFocus]'`

`'*[autoFocus=true]'`

...with `component.down` and `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` (and others), but no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[autoFocus]')` should work, provided that the textfield is instantiated.

Comment: Ok, I found a solution. The query itself is not the problem! It works as it should. If I query for components in the window's initComponent() method (after this.callParent(arguments)), the component could not be found for some reason. [If I hook myself into the 'show'-event](https://gist.github.com/rkrx/2ddf72aa04765ae262fd), the `.focus()` operation works.

Comment: Yeah, during `initComponent` they may not be instantiated yet.